# Python CGI filedownload name change

Tags: python, cgi

I was trying to do file download using CGI, It's works fine excpt the downloaded file has the name of the python script file.

My code :

```
#Source file name : download.py
#HTTP Header
fileName='downloadedFile'
print "Content-Type:application/octet-stream; name=\"%s\"\r\n" %fileName;
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"%s\"\r\n\n" %fileName;

data= ''

try:
    with open(fullPath,'rb') as fo: 
        data = fo.read();
    print data 
except Exception as e:
    print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
    print '<br>Exception :'
    print e
```

The file downloads with a name `download.py` instead of `downloadedFile`. How can I set the downloaded file name to `downloadedFile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you copy this from PHP ? (PHP uses `;` but Python doesn't need it)

You have too many `\n`. In Python `print` adds `\n` automatically.

After first header (first `print`) you had two `\n\n` (with '\n' added by `print`) so after header you had empty line which means end of headers. So second line with name wasn't threated as header but as part of body.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

fullpath = 'images/normal.png'
filename = 'hello_world.png'

print 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="%s"' % filename
print 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="%s"' % filename
print "Content-Length: " + str(os.stat(fullpath).st_size)
print    # empty line between headers and body
#sys.stdout.flush()

try:
    with open(fullpath, 'rb') as fo: 
        print fo.read()
except Exception as e:
    print 'Content-type:text/html'
    print    # empty line between headers and body
    print 'Exception :', e
```